# Proftpd: disable identity switch

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-14.04, proftpd

So, I'm running proFTPD (latest),on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Server 64.

Once a client has successfully authenticated, Proftpd (running as root) switches the new process to the identity/privileges of the authenticated user: all disk operations (read/writes) occurs under than privileges.

I'm looking for a way to perform disk operations as root user.

Thnaks

Danny P.

Comment: Are your clients using FTP/FTPS, or SFTP?  I ask because the necessary configurations are slightly different for the two protocols.

Comment: Just plain FTP, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of accomplishing this come to mind.

First, you could construct/use a separate [`AuthUserFile`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/AuthFiles.html), and in that file, you define an entry for your user, and that user the UID of 0.  This will effectively make your user a root user -- *but only for FTP logins*.  Note that if you use this approach, you will also need to allow root logins (which ProFTPD rejects by default) using:

```
RootLogin on
```

in your `proftpd.conf`.

Alternatively, you could use the [`UserOwner`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#UserOwner) directive, and specify that user "root" should be used, but only in designated directories.  For example:

```
<Directory /path/to/some/dir>
  # In this directory, file uploads/writes happen as the root user
  UserOwner root
</Directory>
```

This second approach can be used with *all* of your FTP clients, rather than just specific users, but can be restricted to specific users if need be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works like a charm. RootLogin parameter must be set to "On" in the configuration file.